# Setting IntelliJ compiler args in Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, javac

I need to add the `-parameters` java compiler parameter for my tests to succeed. I can do this in gradle already for `./gradlew build` to work, or manually by adding `-parameters` under IntelliJ `Settings > Build.. > Compiler > Java Compiler > Additional command line parameters:` so they work in the IDE, but I don't want everyone who checks out this repo to have to do a manual step.

My `.ipr` file does show

`<component name="JavacSettings">
    <option name="ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS_STRING" value="-parameters" />
 </component>`

after setting it manually, but is it possible to configure the idea plugin in gradle so `./gradlew idea` just does all the work?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do that with the new "Proof-of-concept" plugin from JetBrains: 
[gradle-idea-ext-plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext) with following configuration:

```
idea.project.settings {
    compiler {
        javac {
            javacAdditionalOptions "-parameters"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and keep on a getting a value is null when in a multimodule project.  Have you run it in that context? https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/issues/58

Comment: @PeterKahn I actually use that in multi module project. Javac options are set on every Gradle sync.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if I'm on too old or too new a version of gradle because I tried a simple example which is what I put up in the #58 issue.  So, what version of gradle and plugin?

Comment: I am using gradle composite build. Is it possible to set different compiler args for different modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `ipr` file as XML and add the component node. The [official documentation has an example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html#sec:idea_modify_xml) how to do this:

```
idea.project.ipr {
    withXml { provider ->
        provider.node.component
                .find { it.@name == 'VcsDirectoryMappings' }
                .mapping.@vcs = 'Git'
    }
}
```

But you will be limited to the IDEA file project structure (as opposed to the .idea directory structure).